# Having a sub domain at :8080 being redirected from :80/sub

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to set up a server at port 8080 behind Nginx.

I want that when a attempt to reach myserver/sub, all after /sub is redirected to 8080, without sub. At the moment, I'm unable to remove sub from the URL.

my location config is:

```
location /sub
{
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
  Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_pass_header Upgrade;
  proxy_pass_header Connection;
  rewrite /sub/(.*) /$1 break;
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
}
```

Has you can see, I have the in developpement version a nginx to proxy websocket...

To be clear: What I want is that if I write the url myserver/sub/connect it will foward the equivalent of myserver:8080/connect, and url myserver/sub will be equivalent to myserver:8080. User however must not know that it is happening on the port 8080, and must think that every thing is in /sub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, read the documentation: http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass
and replace your:

```
location /sub
{
  [...]
  rewrite /sub/(.*) /$1 break;
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
}
```

with

```
location /sub/ {
    [...]
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
}
```

Comment: Sadly, It almost works

it does allow me to see the main page of the server at 8080, but the image in 8080/static aren't loaded. It tries to fetch them at :80/static instead of :80/substatic or :8080/static

Last point: it shows to url has subSometing (subAuth, substatic) instead of sub/Auth or sub/static has expected. Any Idea?